# Discord.JS 13 slash command display a targets users specific user role in and embed,

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to make a slash command that displays a users specific roles when the command is issued.

```
run: async (client, interaction) => {
try{
    const { member, channelId, guildId, applicationId, 
            commandName, deferred, replied, ephemeral, 
            options, id, createdTimestamp , roles, cache
    } = interaction; 
    const { guild } = member;
    let UserOption = options.getUser("which_user");
    if(!UserOption) UserOption = member.user;
    try{
        await guild.members.fetch();
        const member = guild.members.cache.get(UserOption.id);
        const roles = member.roles;
        const userFlags = UserOption.flags.toArray();
        const activity = UserOption.presence?.activities[0];
        //create the EMBED
        const embeduserinfo = new MessageEmbed()
        embeduserinfo.setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true, size: 512 }))
        embeduserinfo.setAuthor("Information about:   " + member.user.username + "#" + member.user.discriminator, member.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }), "https://discord.gg/FQGXbypRf8")
        embeduserinfo.addField('**❱ Username:**',`<@${member.user.id}>\n\`${member.user.tag}\``,true)
        //embeduserinfo.addField('**❱ ID:**',`\`${member.id}\``,true)
        embeduserinfo.addField('**❱ Avatar:**',`[\`Link to avatar\`](${member.user.displayAvatarURL({ format: "png" })})`,true)
        embeduserinfo.addField('**❱ Joined Discord:**', "\`"+moment(member.user.createdTimestamp).format("DD/MM/YYYY") + "\`\n" + "`"+ moment(member.user.createdTimestamp).format("hh:mm:ss") + "\`",true)
        embeduserinfo.addField('**❱ Joined MetroVan:**', "\`"+moment(member.joinedTimestamp).format("DD/MM/YYYY") + "\`\n" + "`"+ moment(member.joinedTimestamp).format("hh:mm:ss")+ "\`",true)
        //embeduserinfo.addField(`❱ [${roles.cache.size}] Roles: `, roles.cache.size < 25 ? Array.from(roles.cache.values()).sort((a, b) => b.rawPosition - a.rawPosition).map(role => `<@&${role.id}>`).join(', ') : roles.cache.size > 25 ? trimArray(roles.cache) : 'None')
        if (roles.cache.find(r => r.id === "893330818624282656"))
        {
            embeduserinfo.addField("test")
        }
        embeduserinfo.setColor(ee.color)
        embeduserinfo.setFooter(ee.footertext, ee.footericon)
        //send the EMBED
        interaction.reply({embeds: [embeduserinfo], ephemeral: false})
      }catch (e){
        console.log(e)
      }
} catch (e) {
    console.log(String(e.stack).bgRed)
}
```

}
}

if targeted member has role 893330818624282656 display this embed.addField

```
        if (roles.cache.find(r => r.id === "893330818624282656"))
    {
        embeduserinfo.addField("test")
    }
```

Step by step goal

- User 1 uses slash command to view users 2 profile
- User 1 executes slash command /profile @user2
- An embedd is sent to the channel the command is executed in with ephemeral: true (changed in code once programming is completed)
- User 2 will have one of three roles.
- 123456789 / 123456788 / 123456787
- DMS OPEN / DMS ASK / DMS CLOSED

Embed will display one of the 3 roles as

- DMS ARE OPEN
- YOU MUST ASKED TO DM IN #CHANNEL
- DMS ARE CLOSED

Comment: It’s hard to tell what you want - please clarify your goal and how what you are doing right now doesn’t work

Comment: What's the question? On the surface your code seems fine

Comment: also for context i get an error when this code is executed on the server
RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values must be non-empty strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem

```js
embeduserinfo.addField("test")
```

`test` is the name of the field but there is no value

If you want to add an empty value that won’t throw an error, do this:

```js
embeduserinfo.addField("test", "** **")
```

Or if you want to make it an empty name, just reverse the parameters. Otherwise you should just make it the value it should have.